# less or equal relation with largest element of natural number list

Tags: coq

I want to use definition of list_max_le. After applying "Search list_max_le" I  get nothing. How I can define  list_max_le in Coq?

Answer (score 1):

```
Require Import List.
Search "list" "max".
```

by using quotes `"` you search for definitions with has the specified string in its *name*.
The search above produces the result

```
list_max: list nat -> nat
list_max_le:
  forall (l : list nat) (n : nat), list_max l <= n <-> Forall (fun k : nat => k <= n) l
list_max_app:
  forall l1 l2 : list nat, list_max (l1 ++ l2) = Nat.max (list_max l1) (list_max l2)
list_max_lt:
  forall [l : list nat] (n : nat),
  l <> nil -> list_max l < n <-> Forall (fun k : nat => k < n) l
```

If you want to see the definition of `list_max_le`, you use the `Print` command

```
Print list_max_le.
```

but in this case the definition is not very readable.

If you Search without `"`, you search with a pattern that tries to match part of the type definition.

So if you search

```
Search list_max.
```

You search for all definitions that contains the *term* `list_max`.

```
list_max_le:
  forall (l : list nat) (n : nat), list_max l <= n <-> Forall (fun k : nat => k <= n) l
list_max_app:
  forall l1 l2 : list nat, list_max (l1 ++ l2) = Nat.max (list_max l1) (list_max l2)
list_max_lt:
  forall [l : list nat] (n : nat),
  l <> nil -> list_max l < n <-> Forall (fun k : nat => k < n) l
```

You can have many strings and terms to refine your search.
As an example, if you want som lemma about induction on lists, it is probably called something with "ind" in its name, and has the `list` term in its type (not necessarily in its name).  So you can try

```
Search  "ind" list.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have `Require Import List.` so that `Check list_max_le.` works. A `Search list_max_le.` doesn't show anything because `Search` searches lemmas which have the searched term in their type/statement, but there is no lemma which has `list_max_le` in its type. You could do `Search "list_max_le".` to search for a lemma with `list_max_le` in its name.

If the question is "how do I find out which module to require?": I either google for "Coq standard library `lemma name`" or grep through the theories folder of the Coq sources. Maybe we should have a file which includes the complete standard library to make searching lemmas easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `Require Import List.`

`Search "max" "list".`

will show you all that is known about maximum and list.

Comment: I have added the definition of list_max_le in Coq script. But still I get this message "list_max_le not a defined object".

Comment: weird, can you minimize your script and show it to us?

Comment: I have lemma whose statement is that if greatest value in  the natural number list is zero then  value at at any nth index is also zero. To prove sub goal " Forall (fun x : nat => x <= 0) l" I am applying "rewrite <- list_max_le." But there is meassage "The reference list_max_le was not found in the current
environment."

Comment: Do you have ```Require Import List.``` as first line of your file? What ```Search "list" "max".``` returns?